# Slow query execution using ODBC 32

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, odbc

When executing a simple select query on a SQL Server 2012 system, the execution time is very different if I use OLE or ODBC 32bit. Unfortunately I am forced to use ODBC 32bit.

The Query:

```
SELECT 
  ID_Subjekt, 
  Adresse, 
  Vorname, 
  Name, 
  Strasse, 
  HausNr, 
  HausNrZusatz, 
  WohnungsNr,       
  PLZ, 
  Ort
FROM kunde..VR_ISE_d3_Adressen 
WHERE ID_Subjekt = '8751'
AND Adresse = 'Fritz, Furrenstrasse 8B, 8840 Einsiedeln'
AND Name = 'Züger'
AND Vorname = 'Fritz'
AND Strasse = 'Furrenstrasse'
AND HausNr = '8'
AND HausNrZusatz = 'B'
AND WohnungsNr = ''
AND PLZ = '8840' 
AND Ort = 'Einsiedeln'
```

Using OLE it takes some ms (92 Reads). The same query with the same user needs over a million reads (12 seconds) when I use ODBC.

Can someone please point me in the right direction for solving this performance issue?

What I also do not understand is why the two connections lead to different execution plans in the db? I have uploaded the two execution plans to my webserver: http://goo.gl/8LBJpk

Comment: My guess is that you're dealing with two different plans, perhaps caused by different statement set options.  Here is a discovery query to look at the plans and other related information to get you started in the right direction: `select * from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) qp cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st cross apply sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(cp.plan_handle) pa where st.text not like '%dm_exec_cached_plans%' and st.text like '%VR_ISE_d3_Adressen%' and pa.attribute = 'set_options';`

Comment: If you are able to, feel free to put the output into your question for further review (most notably the query plan XML and the set_options attribute value).

Comment: Is `ID_Subjekt` a `CHAR` column and not an integer?

Comment: @ThomasStringer I have executed the query and filtered out the concerning lines. The result is packed in a zip file which you can download here: http://goo.gl/8LBJpk

Comment: From the query, it looks like you are using the ODBC cursor API to spool back rows from the server. Are you sure this is the same query in both plans?